# White screen in production of ionic capacitor android app

Tags: android, ionic-framework, google-play-services, capacitor

I am using Angular 11 and ionic 5 for my app. And it runs without any errors on my device from the android studio in development. But when I sign my code and upload it for internal or closed (Alpha, Beta) testing on playstore,I see my splash screen for less than half a second and then a blank white screen.

I am using Sentry to log errors so I can debug my app during production. But I see no error in sentry at this point.

So my question is, how can I figure out what is going wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

White screen usually means that an there is an error!

What I think you should do:

1. Test using production mode on your device in android studio. You should see the error in the logs.
2. Use a 3rd party like Browserstack to upload your app and see if you get any errors.
3. Check if you first ask for permissions before you use any device native functionality
4. If you still cant find the error, update all your libraries to the latest version
5. If nothing else works, start deleting/commenting parts of the app until it finally works. Start with the 3rd party plugins or push notifications, then any ionic plugin. Using this you should be able to identify where the problem is.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. None of the above is helpful because app was crashing without showing even the splash screen. I solved it by looking at ADB Logcat. There i found that the capacitor plugin was missing in classpath. Then this thread solved the issue https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/739#issuecomment-855915935